# pivot_longer across multiple columns, how to use names_pattern parameter

Tags: r, tidyr

```
df_wide <- structure(list(name = c("Crushers GC", "4Aces GC"), first_name = c("Charles", 
"Peter"), last_name = c("Howell III", "Uihlein"), first_name_1 = c("Paul", 
"Pat"), last_name_1 = c("Casey", "Perez"), first_name_2 = c("Bryson", 
"Dustin"), last_name_2 = c("DeChambeau", "Johnson"), first_name_3 = c("Anirban", 
"Patrick"), last_name_3 = c("Lahiri", "Reed")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

name        first_name last_name  first_name_1 last_name_1 first_name_2 last_name_2 first_name_3 last_name_3
  <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>      
1 Crushers GC Charles    Howell III Paul         Casey       Bryson       DeChambeau  Anirban      Lahiri     
2 4Aces GC    Peter      Uihlein    Pat          Perez       Dustin       Johnson     Patrick      Reed
```

Our goal is to `pivot_longer` into a dataframe with 3 columns `name`, `first`, `last`, the code seems like it should be simple however we are not sure what value to pass to `names_pattern`, we have:

```
zed %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name,
                      names_to = c("fname", "lname"),
                      names_pattern = "???")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the way to go:

```r
df_wide %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name,
                      names_pattern = "(.*_name).*",
                      names_to = ".value")

#   name        first_name last_name 
# 1 Crushers GC Charles    Howell III
# 2 Crushers GC Paul       Casey     
# 3 Crushers GC Bryson     DeChambeau
# 4 Crushers GC Anirban    Lahiri    
# 5 4Aces GC    Peter      Uihlein   
# 6 4Aces GC    Pat        Perez     
# 7 4Aces GC    Dustin     Johnson   
# 8 4Aces GC    Patrick    Reed
```

**Explanation:**

You should define the pattern of existing columns in `names_pattern`. In this case, you only want one group that is either `last_name` or `first_name`. You should use regex to define those:

```
(.*_name).*
```

This will match every column that contains `_name`. The parenthesis are meant to capture groups. You only need the first part of the column names (so, not the _1, _2) in your expected output, so we use parenthesis only for one group. This is why there is only one `names_to` element.

In `names_to`, where you define new column names, `.value` refers to:

> ".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name
> defines the name of the output column containing the cell values,
> overriding values_to entirely.

Here, `.value` refers to whatever matches `(.*_name)`, so both `first_name` and `last_name`. And that is why we end up with two columns. If there were `middle_name`, `middle_name_1`, ... columns in the original data.frame, we would end up with a third `middle_name` column.

Comment: thank you. why does this work as expected? what are `(.*_name).*` and `.value` doing here?

Comment: Love these elaborated explanations, even better than the help manual :) +1!