# How to set names_sep and/or names_pattern in pivot_longer function

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

I am trying to use `pivot_longer` in one go

By omitting the `names_sep` argument it turns me back the error reported below:

```
mtcars %>%    
  pivot_longer(c(1:3, 6:7), names_to = c('name1', 'name2'),
               values_to = c('values_1', 'values_2'))
```

> Error in `pivot_longer()`:
> ! If you supply multiple names in `names_to` you must also supply one of `names_sep`
> or `names_pattern`.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

But when I add it in the function, it turns me back the following error

> Error in `pivot_longer()`:
> ! `values_to` must have size 1, not size 2.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> Warning message:
> Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 5 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

However, I am not sure what this error is referred to and in general how these arguments (`names_sep` and `names_pattern`).

The expected output is given by the same code where two `pivot_longer` functions are used:

```
mtcars %>%    
  pivot_longer(1:3, names_to = 'name1', values_to = 'values1') %>%    
  pivot_longer(6:7, names_to = 'name2', values_to = 'values2')
```

Comment: This looks like the expected output and error. Why do you want to do this? Note that you are duplicating each rows in your expected output.  Why not  `pivot_longer(mtcars, c(1:3, 6:7))`?

Comment: The fact that you use `c(1:3, 6:7)` does *not* tell at all that you want to divide your pivoting in two groups. To do so, it's preferable to have column names that reflects it, i.e. col1_gr1, col2_gr1, col1_gr2..., and then you can use `pivot_longer` more easily

Comment: For an explanation of how `names_pattern`  works, you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76587653/13460602

Comment: Thanks, but in this case since variables names in columns diffre, I thiink that for this case this wont'be that useful

Comment: Can you help us understand the downside of the working code at the bottom? That seems like it might be the most direct way to pivot in this case, where you know the positions but not the names of the columns.